# How to find end date based on start date & duration

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I developed an online training registration application for my organisation. In this application, we have `StartDate`, `Duration`, `Duration Type` columns along with some other columns and don't have an `EndDate` column.

Now I'm facing the challenge to find the end date, based on `StartDate` & `Duration`.

Please help to get this solved.

My table data:

[image: Table Data Attached]

Expected output:

[image: Expected Data Attached]

Comment: So what's stopping you? Why isn't what you have tried not working? Considering you designed the database, then getting an end date (just adding the duration) is quite a trivial task compared to what you have already done.

Comment: Why is `2020-09-06` plus 2 hours still `2020-09-06` and not `2020-09-06T02:00:00`?

Comment: Also, what version of SQL Server? 2008 is completely unsupported now, and has been for over a year.

Comment: @Larnu, As per Application requirement, we are not capturing ENDDATE. But while generating Reports we need ENDDATE for our analytics.

Both STARTDATE and ENDDATE are defined as DATE columns. So i don't want Time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you please check this as per query ill-prepared the short example.

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
(
    StartDate DATETIME,
    EenDate DATETIME  NULL,
    Duration INT,
    Type NVARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('2020-08-18',NULL,15,'Days'),
('2020-08-18',NULL,10,'Month'),
('2020-08-18',NULL,10,'Hours'),
('2020-08-18',NULL,2,'Year')

SELECT * FROM @table

SELECT StartDate,CASE WHEN [Type] = 'Days' THEN CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(DAY,Duration,StartDate))
WHEN [Type] = 'Month' THEN CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(MONTH,Duration,StartDate))
WHEN [Type] = 'Hours' THEN CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(HOUR,Duration,StartDate))
WHEN [Type] = 'Year' THEN CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(YEAR,Duration,StartDate))
END EenDate,
Duration,Type FROM @table
```

Output

[image: Output]

Comment: Thanks for your Query and It works when Type  'Days and Months' only.It doesn't work when Type is 'Hours'.

Comment: Yes, we can add another option adding FY can you please check the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks You So Much for your help !! Below query returned exact expected Output.

SELECT StartDate,CASE WHEN [Type] = 'Days' THEN CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(DAY,Duration,StartDate))
WHEN [Type] = 'Months' THEN CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(MONTH,Duration,StartDate))
WHEN [Type] = 'Hours' THEN CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(HOUR, Duration, cast(cast(StartDate as date) as datetime)))
WHEN [Type] = 'Year' THEN CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(YEAR,Duration,StartDate))
END EndDate,
Duration,Type FROM Testing1

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to use a `CASE` expression here to achieve this. Due to a month having a variable duration, you can't convert those periods into a more generic value (such as converting the periods to minutes and adding that). "1 Month" from 01 February 2019 is only 28 days, however, from 01 March 2020 it's 31 days.

This results in something like this:

```sql
SELECT YT.StartDatY,
       CASE DurationType WHEN 'Minutes' THEN DATEADD(MINUTE,YT.Duration,UT.StartDate)
                         WHEN 'Hours' THEN DATEADD(HOUR,YT.Duration,UT.StartDate)
                         WHEN 'Days' THEN DATEADD(DAY,YT.Duration,UT.StartDate)
                         WHEN 'Months' THEN DATEADD(MONTH,YT.Duration,UT.StartDate)
                         WHEN 'Years' THEN DATEADD(Year,YT.Duration,UT.StartDate)
       END AS EndDate,
       YT.Duration,
       YT.DurationType
FROM dbo.YourTable YT;
```

Comment: I'm getting below Error.
Msg 9810, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The datepart hour is not supported by date function dateadd for data type date.

Comment: I *assumed* that your were using a date and time datatype, rather than a `date`, @Rummy , as you want to add hours to your `StartDate`. You'll need to convert it to a `datetime`/`datetime2(0)` in the `DATEADD`. You can't add hours to a `date` as it contains no time portion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use function DATEADD to find end date.

```
DATEADD (datepart , number , date )
```

You can add various type of duration (year, month, day, hour, minute, second, etc)

For example to add one month to date you can do:

```
SELECT DATEADD(month, 1, '20200915');
```

Answer (score 0):

Below query returned exact expected output.

```
SELECT StartDate,CASE WHEN [Type] = 'Days' THEN CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(DAY,Duration,StartDate))
WHEN [Type] = 'Months' THEN CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(MONTH,Duration,StartDate))
WHEN [Type] = 'Hours' THEN CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(HOUR, Duration, cast(cast(StartDate as date) as datetime)))
WHEN [Type] = 'Year' THEN CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(YEAR,Duration,StartDate))
END EndDate,
Duration,Type FROM Testing1
```